# How to avoid repeating "object.method()" in C#?

Tags: c#, object, methods

I have to apply a method to an object in C# but I have to do it multiple times

```
stud1.setGrade(90);  stud1.setGrade(100);  stud1.setGrade(90);  stud1.setGrade(50);
```

You get the point... The thing is I know there is a way to avoid that and just put it like this:

```
stud1.setGrade(90)
     .setGrade(100)
     .setGrade(70);
```

But I don't remember if that's correct in C#, I saw it in another programming language although I don't remember if that is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Can you post the "setGrade" method?

Comment: Would a `SetGrades(90,100,70)` method suffice?

Comment: Search term you are looking for is "fluent interface". LINQ (C#) and  jQuery (JavaScript) are examples of such chaining.

Comment: Also known as "cascade" idiom. Simply `return this` or its equivalent in whatever language you wish to use it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible when setGrade() returns an instance of itself or when you write an extension method called setGrade() (for the class) that returns an instance of itself.

```
public static Student SetGrade(this Student student, int value) {
  student.setGrade(value);
  return student;
}
```

this can then be used similar to:

```
stud1.SetGrade(90)
 .SetGrade(100)
 .SetGrade(70);
```

Answer (score 11):

Why dont you add the values you want to set into an array and then use a foreach to call .setGrade?

```
int[] values = int[] {90, 100, 70};

foreach(int value in values)
{
  stud1.setGrade(value);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just have `SetGrade` return `this`.

```
public Student SetGrade(int grade) {
    this.Grade = grade;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me introduce the concept of [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to you. `List` is a data structure to store homogeneous data. You can use `List` for your scenario.

```
List<int> myGrades=new List<int>();
myGrades.Add(90);
myGrades.Add(100);
myGrades.Add(70); //adding all the grades
//we will use foreach to loop through all the elements
foreach(int g in myGrades)
{
 stud1.setGrade(g); //all grades are set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can take *n* number of values..

```
 private void SetGrade(params int[] grades)
        {
            foreach (var grade in grades)
            {
                this.Grade = grade;
            }
        }
```

Calling `SetGrade` method is easier:

```
SetGrade(90, 100, 70);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the class (or as an exercise) you can also write an extension with the `params` keyword.

```
public static class StudentExtensions
{
    public static void SetGrades(this Student student, params int[] values)
    {
        foreach (int grade in values)
        {
            student.SetGrade(grade);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
stud1.SetGrades(90, 100, 70, 50);
```

(Of course you don't have to write it as an extension.)